# How to use the result of a function at each node in Cplex Python API?

Tags: cplex

I used `strong_branching` function in Python and it shows scores in one node. How can I get these scores for each variable at each node?

**EDIT:**

```
class call4clone(CPX_CB.BranchCallback):
       def __call__(self):
         print("Up-Var: ", self.get_upper_bounds(), "Down-Var: ",self.get_lower_bounds(), sep="\n")

def MyCode():
    cplexorig = cplx.Cplex("LPassign.LP")
    //Create Clone
    clone = cplx.Cplex(cplexorig)
    clone.set_problem_type(clone.problem_type.LP)
    clone.register_callback(call4clone)
    clone.solve()
    vars = list(range(clone.variables.get_num()))
    result = clone.advanced.strong_branching(vars, itlim)
    print("result of Up and Down StrongBranching: ",result)
    ...
    cplexorig.solve()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `strong_branching` is not designed to be invoked on node LPs. What you can do is the following:

1. Create a copy/clone of your model.
2. Register a callback (legacy branch callback or generic callback with `BRANCHING` context)
3. In the callback, fetch the local variable bounds at the current node, apply them to your copy of the model and the call `strong_branch` on that copy.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. According to your answer, I edited my code But I didn't understand where should I apply variable bounds to copy of the model?

Comment: Don't call `solve` on the clone. Instead register the callback as `cb = cplexorig.register_callback(call4clone)` and then set `cb.clone = clone` so that callback has a reference to the clone. Then call `cplexorig.solve()`. Now in the callback you can get the current bounds and apply them to `self.clone`. After this you can call `self.clone.advanced.strong_branching`. This will apply strong branching on the clone with the current bounds.